# Trac ticket-custom permission

Tags: checkbox, permissions, trac

I created a custom field checkbox in trac. Written [here](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTicketsCustomFields).

How to make the field were only available for users to TRAC_ADMIN?

example trac.ini

```
[ticket-custom]
newfield = checkbox
newfield.label = Checkbox field name
newfield.value = 0
newfield.permissions = TRAC_ADMIN
```

newfield.permissions - does not work

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [BlackMagicTicketTweaksPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/BlackMagicTicketTweaksPlugin). The feature is proposed in [#9289](https://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/9289), and I will probably work on adding the feature to Trac for release 1.4 (probably about a year away since 1.2 is just about to come out).